# VBA script Not Copying Data - Inserting #REF

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have 1 workbook with multiple sheets and I am running into an issue copying over data from one sheet to another.

Sheets - "ALL CONTACTS" & "MAA DATA"

There are 4 columns where I want data copied from "MAA DATA" to "ALL CONTACTS". There is a header and data in both sheets. For MAA DATA the columns are: E, G, H, J. All starting from row 2. The values are pasted to "ALL CONTACTS" Columns A, B, C, D starting at row 7.

I used the following to copy the data over to "ALL CONTACTS" and it works for 2 columns with no issues, but column B and D in "ALL CONTACTS" begin to return #REF!: `Sheets("MAA Data").Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Copy Sheets("ALL CONTACTS").Range("A7")`

Full code below for reference. What am I doing wrong? I have been at it for hours.

```
Sub ImportMAA()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
MAAPath = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\MAA.xls"
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(MAAPath)
Set ws = wb1.Sheets("MAA Data")
Set ws2Email = wb2.Sheets("MAA")

'' Copy the "Sent Emails" worksheet to wb1.
ws2Email.Copy Before:=ws
wb2.Close


'' Delete existing "Sent Email" worksheet.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ws.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


'' Rename new sheet to "Sent Emails".
wb1.Sheets("MAA").Name = "MAA Data"

'' Delete Extra Row at top
Sheets("MAA Data").Select
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

'' Copy account name to ALL CONTACTS Sheet
Sheets("MAA Data").Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Copy Sheets("ALL CONTACTS").Range("A7")

'' Copy first name to ALL CONTACTS Sheet
Sheets("MAA Data").Range("H2", Range("H2").End(xlDown)).Copy Sheets("ALL CONTACTS").Range("B7")

'' Copy email to ALL CONTACTS Sheet
Sheets("MAA Data").Range("J2", Range("J2").End(xlDown)).Copy Sheets("ALL CONTACTS").Range("C7")

'' Copy last name to ALL CONTACTS Sheet
Sheets("MAA Data").Range("G2", Range("G2").End(xlDown)).Copy Sheets("ALL CONTACTS").Range("D7")

'' Update all columns proper
Worksheets("ALL CONTACTS").Activate
[A:A] = [INDEX(PROPER(A:A),)]
[B:B] = [INDEX(PROPER(B:B),)]
[C:C] = [INDEX(lower(C:C),)]
[D:D] = [INDEX(PROPER(D:D),)]


End Sub
```